# how can make a div like a box like in image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi iam trying to do this

When i open page i need a popup at the center of page and so i created a div and set its display as 'none' .In document.ready i made it like

```
$("document").ready(function (){
   $(".box").show();


});
```

so it will show the div.

But i want my div as like a popup like in attached image. how can i make a div like that witha 3d small shading and all??

[image]

updated code

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
            box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
```

[image]

It giving only bottom and right shadow.

Comment: look for CSS property `box-shadow`.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

Comment: please check my updated question with images

Comment: Have you read any of the comments? Read about [**`box-shadow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Comment: If you read the documentation, you'd find that those values can be changed to alter the position of your box shadow. Change them to how you want them.

Comment: See my answer for what exactly you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `.box { box-shadow:-1px 2px 0.2em grey }` in the CSS should make it somehow like the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
.box {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5); /* x-offset y-offset blur size color */
}
```

For multi browser support, use prefixes like:

-o-box-shadow
-ms-box-shadow
-moz-box-shadow
-webkit-box-shadow

To get the desired result, play around with the x-offset, y-offset, blur and size properties.

Try something like this:

```
box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px #777;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create it with help of http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow :

```
.scenario-callout-text-right {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```